# EF cannot translate query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

I have query for getting data

```
await _dbContext.VwJobSupplierWithScores
                .Where(x => x.JobId == jobId && x.SupplierKey == supplierKey)
                .OrderBy(x => x.SpendCurrencyJob)
                .Select((x, i) => new {item = x, index = i})
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync())!,
```

But for some reasons EF cannot translate it and I get this error

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(x => (Guid?)x.JobId == __jobId_0 && x.SupplierKey == __supplierKey_1)
> .OrderBy(x => x.PurchaseOrderValueCurrencyJob)
> .Select((x, i) => new {
> item = x,
> index = i
> })' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

How I can write it correctly, that LINQ can translate it?

Comment: The fact that LINQ code compiles does not guarantee that a specific LINQ provider will support it at run time. LINQ to Entities - the EF LINQ provider, must be able to convert your LINQ query into SQL that it can execute against the database. Obviously that overload of `Select` is not supported as it cannot be translated to SQL. It doesn't seem that you actually need the index anyway but, if you did, i think that you might have to do two separate queries: one to get the item and then another to count the items "less than" that one.

Answer (score 1):

One option, do as the error told you:

```
await _dbContext.VwJobSupplierWithScores
                .Where(x => x.JobId == jobId && x.SupplierKey == supplierKey)
                .OrderBy(x => x.SpendCurrencyJob)
                .AsEnumerable()   
                .Select((x, i) => new {item = x, index = i})
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync())!
```

Another option:

```
var dbObject = await _dbContext.VwJobSupplierWithScores
                .Where(x => x.JobId == jobId && x.SupplierKey == supplierKey)
                .OrderBy(x => x.SpendCurrencyJob)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

var yourmodel = new { item = dbObject, index = 0 };
```

Please note that some parts of your original code are completely pointless. Using the "!" after calling `FirstOrDefault` yourself? If you know there will always be one, just call `First`. The saving of the index? What do you think the index of the first element will be? So... there is actually no point in having your anonymous object, because the data it holds is redundant. I have shown two ways to make your compiler happy, but you should think about why the code does these weird things in the first place.

Comment: Do you know how `AsEnumerable` behaves in this context? We can be sure that `ToList` would retrieve all the records in the query into the app before getting the first of those. Do you know whether `AsEnumerable` does something similar? My guess would be that it creates the full result set on the database and then exposes it via a data reader, allowing you to get just one record and discard the rest of the results. That's probably not as efficient as calling `First` directly but definitely better than `toList`.

Comment: @John No, I have no idea how it is implemented. Since the ORDER BY on the database has to generate the full result set anyway, the question is basically does the EF provider read that result set in chunks or complete before it gives parts of it to the enumerating code. I don't know the implementation details. The second version would make sure only one record is transferred from the database to the client, the first version is less changes in program code and more trusting in the implementation of others.

Comment: I might run a few tests against a big result set and time them to see if that can provide some clues.

Answer (score 0):

Such `Select` overload is not supported by EF and I actually do not see reason to use that. `FirstOrDefaultAsync` will return one entity and Index will be always ZERO:

```cs
await _dbContext.VwJobSupplierWithScores
    .Where(x => x.JobId == jobId && x.SupplierKey == supplierKey)
    .OrderBy(x => x.SpendCurrencyJob)
    .Select(x => new {item = x, index = 0})
    .FirstOrDefaultAync();
```

Answer (score -1):

Your Problem is, the select not matching the objects in `VmJobSupplierQithScores`. EF tries to map your Query to that type. Because you do a select with a different type, it can not translate that query.
You can split your query into something like this.

```
var item = _dbContext.VwJobSupplierWithScores
                .Where(x => x.JobId == jobId && x.SupplierKey == supplierKey)
                .OrderBy(x => x.SpendCurrencyJob).First();

var result = new {item = x, index = 0};
```

Comment: While this would compile and run, it's not really an acceptable solution because it means retrieving every record from the database table into the app first. What if there are millions of records?

Comment: Also, the explanation is off the mark. It's only about the `Select` overload that's not supported.

Comment: I've adjusted my Answer to you comments

Comment: You cannot call First and then Select. Select is not defined for the object returned by First. This won't compile.